# How to create newcommand with Sanskrit Fonts

Tags: fonts, macros, indic

[How to change font size in verse environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30737/how-to-change-font-size-in-verse-environment/30738#30738)

I am working with these fonts (i.e. Aksharyogini / Nakula / Sanskrit 2003)

When i replace \bfseries with any one of these I get error, what am I doing wrong. how would I work with these font types. thanks for your help

```
 \newcommand\RedLine[1]{%
  \textcolor{red}{\fontsize{8}{9.6}\selectfont\bfseries#1}
  }
```

Comment: What are you precisely writing for selecting the font?

Comment: \newcommand\RedLine[1]{%
  \textcolor{red}{\fontsize{8}{9.6}\selectfont\Aksharayogini#1}
  }

Comment: Is `\Aksharayogini` defined as a font selection command with `\newfontfamily` or `\newfontface`?

Comment: @egreg no its not defined, & I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\RedLine` defined in that answer is just an example. In order to get a red line using the current font it's only a matter of saying

```
\newcommand{\RedLine}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
```

In order to use different fonts, you can define them via `\newfontfamily`:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Sanskrit 2003}
\newfontfamily\Aksharyogini{Aksharyogini}
\newfontfamily\Nakula{Nakula}
```

or simply with `\newfontface` if you are not interested in italic or bold variants of those fonts.

Then

```
\begin{verse}\Aksharyogini
<verses>
\end{verse}
```

will print the poem using the Aksharyogini font.

Comment: Sorry but I did not get it. I could color the text using textcolor. What I do not know is how to assign a particular font to it. i.e. any font mentioned above.

Comment: @Aku Please, make your question clearer.

Comment: In my document I want to work with (i.e. Aksharyogini / Nakula / Sanskrit 2003) at various places. I do not know how to do that. my entire document appears in one type of font. I don't know how to use font for a particular paragraph, verse, etc. does this description help?