# How to change font styles in verse environment without setting up a new environment?

Tags: fonts, lyx, verse

This is a related question to:

[How to change font size in verse environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30737/how-to-change-font-size-in-verse-environment)

Although this answer works very well, it does create a new `Verse` environment without the inherent functions of the `verse` package. In the case of LyX, it will be cumbersome to implement.

I wondered, if there is a way to define the font styles in the Preamble—font size, leading, style etc—with all the inherent proprieties of `verse`? It will keep the LyX interface clean and still modifiable through the Preamble.

ps. I tried `\renewenvironment` with simple `\selectfont`, it seems to `erase` the verse functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aletrnative to Werner's, this solution doesn't rewriting of the whole environment. This goes into the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\versefont}{\itshape} % put here whatever font commands you want
\let\myoldverse\verse % now we store the original {verse}
\def\verse{\versefont\myoldverse} % and new {verse} just uses the font and original {verse}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using one of the standard document classes, you can merely add the following to your LaTeX preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\versefont}{}
\renewenvironment{verse}
               {\let\\\@centercr
                \list{}{\itemsep      \z@
                        \itemindent   -1.5em%
                        \listparindent\itemindent
                        \rightmargin  \leftmargin
                        \advance\leftmargin 1.5em}%
                \item\relax\versefont}
               {\endlist}
\makeatother
```

This will allow you to redefine `\versefont` to make your font selections in the preamble, or through the body text using an ERT.

If you're using the [`verse` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/verse), then your preamble should look like this in order to do the same:

```
\usepackage{verse}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\versefont}{}
\renewenvironment{verse}[1][\linewidth]{
  \stepcounter{verse@envctr}%
  \setcounter{poemline}{0}\refstepcounter{poemline}%
  \setcounter{vslineno}{1}%
  \let\\=\@vscentercr
  \list{}{\itemsep \z@
          \itemindent  -\vindent%
          \listparindent\itemindent
          \parsep       \stanzaskip
          \ifdim #1 < \linewidth
            \rightmargin        \z@
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{\linewidth}%
            \addtolength{\leftmargin}{-#1}%
            \addtolength{\leftmargin}{-0.5\leftmargin}%
          \else
            \rightmargin        \leftmargin
          \fi
          \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\vindent}%
          \versefont}
  \item[]}{\endlist}
\makeatother
```

The above code just grabbed the `verse` environment definition from [`verse.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/verse/verse.dtx) and inserted `\versefont` (defined to be empty).

Comment: I'd put `\versefont` before `\list` in both cases, so that it can contain also font size changing commands.