# How to create Index for Verses

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing, verse

I ran into problem of creating index for a book (1200 page) which has around 700 verses and its explanation.

I have one main tex file with the preamble. I have 18 chapters in my book, so I created 18 texfiles which contains the 700 verses. I am using `\include{filename}` to work with one file at a time.

I have no clue about creating index page for the book. I am attaching a screenshot of the format. To begin with I don’t even know how to add first few words of each verse to index page.

Its in sanskrit, and I am using verse environment as shown in the example here [How to center a verse horizontally](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26197/how-to-center-a-verse-horizontally/26211#26211) given by @Herbert

I found index worked it gave the first few words of the verse and page number. I could not get the chapter number and two column output with a line divide in between.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I suspect Xindy would be the way to go, but setting that up for Sanskrit is tricky.  Zdenek Wagner has done work on this, I believe.

The other resource to be aware of is [John Smith's Bombay website](http://bombay.indology.info), that hosts the indexing program sort for Sanskrit.  Again, this is for a competent Unix user, and may require piping between other utilities that change the character encodings.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX, your expertise will be very helpful here. You'd like to choose a better nickname than user107136, wouldn't you?

Comment: As @egreg says, a more descriptive user name would be nice. I've edited to remove the 'signature', as the idea here is that the automatically-inserted user name does the job. I've also marked up the hyperlink to be 'active' in the post.

Comment: Cf [this conversation](http://www.mail-archive.com/xetex@tug.org/msg05254.html) on the XeTeX-mailing list. Might be you want to contact Zdenek Wagner directly -- perhaps you could help him do the testing?