# Numbering and Centering Verse in XeLaTeX

Tags: horizontal-alignment, xetex, numbering

I have followed the steps provided in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/209105/282979).
But in my case the numbering in coming in the left side of the page. but i want it to appear on the right side.

This is how I defined shloka (verse) environment.

```
%% Verses
\usepackage{varwidth}
\newcounter{verse}
\setcounter{verse}{0}
\newenvironment{shloka}
  {\refstepcounter{verse}
   \equation
   \let\theequation\theverse
   \varwidth[b]{\linewidth}
  }
  {\endvarwidth
   \endequation
   \addtocounter{equation}{-1}
  }
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Please add the complete code to produce such output, from `\documentclass{..` to `\end{document}` to make a diagnosis possible.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. I get the number at the right, aligned with the bottom row.